Azure B2C does not receive script information written in HTML files uploaded to storage
I'm trying to customize the "Forgot Password" page look from B2C's Ocean Blue template. I want to remove the screen with the "Change-email" button. The solution after a lot of searching is to use the "Ocean Blue" template, edit it and upload it to the storage account.
However, I can only add CSS to hide the "Change-email" button but cannot delete the entire page. I thought about writing more Script below, but it's still not received when running UserFlow. Does anyone know the reason why?
<body>
    <div id="background_branding_container" data-tenant-branding-background-color="true">
      <img data-tenant-branding-background="true" src="https://tenant.blob.core.windows.net/root/templates/src/backgrounds/1-1.png" alt="Illustration"/>
    </div>
    <div class="container  self_asserted_container " role="presentation">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <img class="companyLogo" data-tenant-branding-logo="true" src="https://tenant.b2clogin.com/static/tenant/templates/images/logo.svg" alt="Company Logo">
                        <div id="api" role="main">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    "use strict";
        $(document).ready(function () {
          console.log("Script Load Successful!");
        });
    </script>
</body>

I tried adding a script but it doesn't load on the B2C interface. I would expect to be able to load the script and then execute the action bypassing the "Change-email" interface after successful Authentication.

Did you enable JS - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#enable-javascript

If you are using a page contract of self-asserted >= 2.1.21 you MUST put all script tags in the <head> tag. See the Page Layout Versions documentation for more information.
You must also enable JavaScript execution, as this is off by default. See Enable JavaScript and page layout versions in Azure Active Directory B2C
